# How to find out the IP of MAC Address?

Tags: cisco

Below is the "terminal monitor" output

```
%PM-4-ERR_DISABLE: security-violation error detected on Gi1/0/35, putting Gi1/0/35 in err-disable state

%AUTHMGR-5-SECURITY_VIOLATION: Security violation on the interface GigabitEthernet1/0/35, new MAC address (0800.2754.a0df) is seen.AuditSessionID Unassigned
```

After timeleft(sec) ends it is coming back; The problem is this keeps happening and I can not find this "0800.2754.a0df" and do not understand why this MAC tries to get assigned on this interface.

It is like this device tries to get assigned with my desktop's MAC Address, looks like  a MAC address conflict.

```
#show errdisable recovery

Timer interval: 300 seconds

Interfaces that will be enabled at the next timeout:

Interface Errdisable reason Time left(sec)

Gi1/0/35 security-violation 183
```

It is happening on my desktop which has wired and wireless NIC. How can I find the IP of this MAC address? The switch is 2960x cisco.

Thanks

Comment: Not all MAC addresses are required to have an IP address in the sense you mean. Some could have an IPv4 address, and/or IPv6 could have multiple addresses and address types associated with the MAC address. There are other network protocols, too, although rare, that may be associated with a MAC address. Ethernet (MAC addressing) does not know or care which network protocol it carries in its payload, and neither does a network protocol care which data-link protocol carries it..

Comment: So is the mac address the same as your desktop PC? Have you tried removing the security config on the port so that the device can be on the network long enough for it to get an IP address?

Answer (score 6):

Generally to find the IP address associated to a MAC Address, the easiest way is to look in the ARP tables.
You can lookup in the the table of any device within the same (V)LAN but the device that is the most likely to have the info is the router that act as the gateway for this (V)LAN.

On most network devices, the command is either

```
show arp
```

or

```
show ip arp
```

Most routers can also refine the search, for example by VLAN with a command like

```
show ip arp interface vlan 100
```

Otherwise if you want to have a hint at what the device which own the mac address is, you can search for the mac address prefix in an [OUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier) lookup tool. It will give you the manufacturer of the Network Interface Card (if this is a physical device) or the hypervisor vendor (if this is a virtual machine).

If the mac address in your post is the real one that bother you, the NIC is made by  PCS Computer Systems GmbH, as can be seen by entering the mac address in the WireShark (no affiliation) [OUI Lookup tool](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html).
[PCS Computer Systems](https://www.pcs.com/en/) sell building access controls and time management solutions, so this should allow you to narrow down your researches.

Of course the most efficient way is still to follow the physical path from the switch port.

Comment: The device might also be using DHCP, so you could check the DHCP server for a lease with that MAC.

Comment: I already did MAC address lookup but did not put in the question. Nobody knew about such a device. "show arp" cmd did not help either, could not find that MAC. thanks

Comment: @hakkican I guess you will have to follow the cables then...

Comment: by experience the fact that nobody is aware of the existence of a specific device in the network doesn't preclude it from existing ;)

Comment: somehow this device is connected to this cisco switch right? this device can not be connected to other network device?

Comment: @hakkican It seems so but we don't have enough information about your network to be affirmative. I saw stranger things on some networks...

Comment: @JFL saw strangers things on some networks. what r u hinting at? what do you want to know about this network to find out this device? There is one switch and a device connected to this switch and this device MAC is conflicting with my desktop MAC. Why would you need to know about whole network?

Comment: @Zac67 of course I did that too. nothing came out of this. Is not there such a tool like traceroute to find out path of this device? or what port this device is connected to? It is strange to google MAC address to find out information about this device instead of  on this cisco switch. how could cisco switch not show any information about this dvice that is connected to itself and even shows it on terminal?  MAC Address, port etc

Comment: @hakkican it is not clear in your post what is connected to GigabitEthernet1/0/35, should we understand that it is a port in access mode on which only your mac is connected?
What are the results of "show mac address-table"  and "show running-config interface gigabitethernet 1/0/35" ? (please edit your post to include those info)

Comment: @hakkican You see the associated port in a switch's MAC table. Just follow the cable plugged into that port. No, there's no Ethernet traceroute as there's no TTL concept.

Comment: As has been mentioned: walk to the switch in question, find port 35, follow the wire to whatever is plugged into the end of it. Diagnose from that point to determine if the device is malfunctioning, or should not be on the network at all, etc.

Comment: @hakkican am I being slow here? You know the port, its g1/0/35. You have asked the question on the [cisco forum](https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/pm-4-err-disable-security-violation-error-detected-catalyst-2960/td-p/4743756) and have said that it has happened ever since you rolled out dot1x. Remove the dot1x from the port, trace the port.

Comment: @JFL There s a label behind the chair on the wall it is 35 to which my desktop's network cable is connected. In the system room, the network cable is coming out from port 35 on the cisco device and it is going to another panel on which there is another label called "35".  This PCS device is connected to port X on the same cisco switch and there is no other way this PCS device can get its MAC address assigned on my port 35 right?  How can I find this PCS device's cable in the system room if I do not know what port it is connected?

Comment: @JFL Imagine two devices connected to the same cisco switch and I am getting the error in my question how could this happen? It is like two devices in race condition to connect to port 35? or two different MAC addresses trying to connect to the same port 35?

Comment: @Footsie could you explain how I can trace the port? thanks

Comment: @JFL "show ip arp interface vlan 100" I do not have this command right after "show ip arp interface"  do u mean "show ip arp vlan" 100" ? can not find PCS device MAC address with those commands